# Chartist always has left spacing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chartist.js

With chartist.js no matter what you do, hide the labels via css or `showLabel: false` there is always that space to the left and bottom.

I am trying to absolutely position the chart to fit in a div, so the chart begins on the very left and draws all the way to the other end without any space or padding.

I have tried many different ways of hiding the grid and labels, they are hidden but that space is still there.

I don't really want to hack the css and do `left:-100px` `width:104%`.

Here are some examples.

On my project the blue chart should have no white space to the left or bottom. The chartist wrapper looks like this.

```
.minimal-chart.ct-chart {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[image]

Even on their site you can see it is no where near flush with the box below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add these options when you initialize it:

chartPadding: {
    left: -40
}